# Ternary with uninitialized bool leads to buffer overflow on macOS

Tags: c++, clang, c-strings, conditional-operator, memory-corruption

The following code leads to very strange behavior.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
{
    std::string x = "";
    std::string y = "a";
    bool b; // Uninitialized!
public:
    void test()
    {
        std::cout << y + (b ? "b" : "") << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    A a;
    a.test();
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of outputting either "ab" or just "a" it actually echos:

```
ab $\321XQ\300\<\246
\\300\324<  \340\353
=X |
```

After finding out that the reason for it was the uninitialized variable `b` I am still curious to why this happens (and only in release build on clang for macos).

Edit: Simplified the example further.

- If I remove `A::x`, it echos `a`.
- If I change it to `y + (b ? "b" : "c")` it echos `ab`
- If `A::b` is not declared last, it echos `a`.

Edit 2:

I guess this post has be come more a "TIL: There is UB" then an actual question.
If you came here and learned about it as well, this video might be interesting for you:

https://youtu.be/ehyHyAIa5so

Comment: This is obviously not complete code, so it's hard to say why your real code might be wrong. Please share a [mcve].

Comment: Almost certainly prior code has trashed your heap or stack. This is innocent code.

Comment: Just because this is where the program crashes or reports an error doesn't mean that's where the problem is. C++ does not work this way. The problem can be anywhere in your code which is why stackoverflow.com's [help] requires you to show a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, then compile, run, and reproduce your problem. See [ask] for more information.

Comment: I (only after asking) tried to write it self contained example and wasn't  able to reproduce it.

I will try more then just address sanitization and update once I found the culprit.

I was just certain that it was here, since the sanitizer did not find another error and changing it to if(b) x+= baz; fixed the problems.

Comment: @MichaelSchmitt That's good! It means you are close to finding the problem. You have a version with the problem, and a version without. The problem is probably somewhere in the difference.

Comment: Do you think I should rephrase it as the original question and answer it myself - or should I leave it as it is, to just state the curiosity part that is left?

Comment: Re: " changing it to if(b) x+= baz; fixed the problems"  -- it probably didn't **fix** the problems; it just made the symptoms go away. They'll be back...

Comment: My best guess is, that the optimized code assumes that a bool is either 0x00000000 or 0x00000001 - and optimizes for speed by also saying, it should do very weird stuff when it is something else. Just like a „don’t care“ state in a Karnaugh map.